# Alternatives to proportional odds mixed effects models

Tags: r, ordinal-data, ordered-logit, odds

I was doing some reading about categorical data analysis (e.g. Agresti (2010): Analysis of Ordinal Categorical Data). Additionally to analysing data with an ordinal response with the help of proportional odds cummulative mixed effects models it seems some people suggest e.g. to use the `glmer()` function from `lme4` in `R` to fit a whole range of models.

My data looks as follows:

1. ordinal response: a five point scale with $1<2<3<4<5$ ($1$ being worst, $3$ being neutral, $5$ being best)
2. one single categorical predictor "type" with 5 levels
3. subjects as random effects term which I would specify in `lme4` syntax: `(type | subjects)` with intercept and slope for every subject.

Every subject saw $320$ items ($40$ for level $1$, $40$ for level $2$, $40$ for level $3$, $160$ for level $4$) and rated every single one of them. The dataset seems quite nice and as it only contains a single predictor is very good to get
acquainted with categorical data analysis.

However, I was wondering if there are alternative ways of analysing such
data apart from treating the response as a continuous variable and using `lmer()` or `aov()`. And if there are any recommendation or advice people can
give here.

Here is an alternative I read about . One could split a dataset with an ordinal response into subsets that each only contain two levels of the ordinal response. There are some questions I have about this. How would you split that dataset into subsets given a $5$ point ordinal response? Based on the ordering of my response the most reasonable choice to me seems: subset $A$ with levels $1$ and $2$, subset $B$ with levels $2$ and $3$, subset $C$ with levels $3$ and $4$, subset $D$ with levels $4$ and $5$. I tried this with the `wine` data set from the `ordinal` package. But this will ungraciously fail because of convergence failures, model unidentifiability etc. (I'm using `lme4 1.1.8`). Here is the wine example:

```
data("wine", package = "ordinal") # the wine dataset
library(lme4)
sub <- wine$rating %in% grep("[1-2]", wine$rating, value = TRUE)
sub12 <- subset(wine, subset = sub)
sub12$rating <- factor(sub12$rating, ordered = FALSE)
glmer12 <- glmer(rating ~ temp + contact + (temp | judge),
                 data = sub12,
                 family = binomial)

# Substituting (1 | judge) for (temp | judge) won't make it better

# Will give no warning
glm12 <- glm(rating ~ temp + contact,
             data = sub12,
             family = binomial)

sub <- wine$rating %in% grep("[2-3]", wine$rating, value = TRUE)
sub23 <- subset(wine, subset = sub)
sub23$rating <- factor(sub23$rating, ordered = FALSE)

glmer23 <- glmer(rating ~ temp + contact + (temp | judge),
                 data = sub23,
                 family = binomial)

sub <- wine$rating %in% grep("[3-4]", wine$rating, value = TRUE)
sub34 <- subset(wine, subset = sub)
sub34$rating <- factor(sub34$rating, ordered = FALSE)
glmer34 <- glmer(rating ~ temp + contact + (temp | judge),
                 data = sub34,
                 family = binomial)
```

Of course the wine dataset is rather tiny (and we have full- or quasi-separation) and mine won't but how likely am
I to run in similar problem if I analyse ordinal data this way?

Comment: why don't you use the very good `ordinal` package ... ?

Comment: I currently do. I wanted to check some alternatives to it.

Comment: it just seems that the process you're describing above is more or less re-inventing the machinery used in standard ordinal model frameworks (including the `ordinal` package) ...

Comment: Yes, when I was asking this question I was unsure how good the clmm() machinery is as there was some debate about whether it correctly deals with multiple random effects. Now that Rune stated it is indeed possible I'm more comfortable using it. However, I'm more familiar with the codebase of `lme4` and I find it an excellent package, reliable and robust in nearly all aspects. That's why I was inquiring as to whether there was a similar approach that would allow me to use it.

Comment: I think the `glmer()` strategy I outlined above is rather a cummulative odds model with non-parallel slopes and thus makes less assumptions than `clmm()` from `ordinal` at the cost of introducing more parameters into the model(s). (Agresti also has a part about his in his 2010 "Analysis of Ordinal Categorical Data".